# how to use django related_name

Tags: python, django

I have two models named Meeting and MeetingMember like this :

```
 class Meeting(models.Model):
      title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
      description = models.TextField()

 class MeetingMember(models.Model):
     CHOICES = [
         ("A", "Accepted"),
         ("R", "Rejected"),
         ("I", "Invited" ),
         ("H", "Host"),
     ]
 
     status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=CHOICES, default="I")
     meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="members")
     email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
```

I need to write a query that first gets all the records in `MeetingMeember` model which belong to the current logged in user like this :

```
meetingmembers  = MeetingMember.objects.filter(email = request.user.email)
```

then i need to the get all the info from the meetings belongs to the  `MeetingMeember` (the second queryset should be `Meeting` object)
i have studied about `related_name` but still can't figure out how can i write this.

Comment: Why do you use an `email` field, and not just a `ForeignKey` to the user. Especially since emails are *not* required to be unique with the standard user model.

Comment: Bcs MeetingMeember model is used to save a list of invited  emails and not all of them should be a registered user

Comment: but it would require at least to make the Django user model working with a unique email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your design an **Meeting object** belongs to multiple **MeetingMember objects** and you can access them using related name `members` like `metting_obj.members.all()` and an MeetingMember object belongs to a single Meeting object and you can assess using the attribute `meeting` like `metting_member_obj.metting`

you can retrieve all **Meeting objects** belongs to **MeetingMember objects** as following:

```
meeting_objs = [meeting_member.meeting for meeting_member in meetingmembers]
```

Comment: But i need to have the result as query format so i can return it in a get_queryset in DRF , i don't need a list

Answer (score 3):

You can filter with:

```
Meeting.objects.filter(
    members__email=request.user.email
)
```

to retrieve all the `Meeting`s for which the `email` of the logged in user is a member.

If you work with the `Member` model, you can use [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to retrieve the `Meeting` object in the same query, then for `some_member`, you can access the related `Meeting` (and info with) `some_member.meeting` without making an extra query:

```
meetingmembers = MeetingMember.objects.filter(
    email=request.user.email
).select_related('meeting')

for member in meetingmenbers:
    print(member.meeting)
```

Comment: I got this error :ValueError: Cannot query "test1": Must be "Meeting" instance.

Comment: @niloofar: can you edit the question with the full traceback? At first sight I would think you somehow aim to serialize something but you pass it a string instead of `Metting` instances.

Answer (score 2):

The **related_name** attribute specifies the name of the reverse relation from the Meeting model back to MeetingMember model.

If you have MeetingMember object like meeting_member and your related_name is 'members' then
meeting_member.members.all() to get all instances of your Meeting model that have a relation to object.